# Scons: how to specify file dependency for 3rd party compile result?

Tags: shell, dependencies, execute, scons, protoc

It seem to me that scons targets are being generated not in declaration sequence. My problem is, I need to generate some code first, I'm using protoc to process a my.proto file into .h and .cc file, I need some pseudo code like this(what should the working code look like?)

```
import os
env=Environment(ENV=os.environ,LIBPATH='/usr/local/lib')
env.ShellExecute('protoc', '--outdir=. --out-lang=cpp', 'my.proto')//produces my.cc
myObj=Object('my.cc')//should wait until 'my.cc' is generated by protoc
Dependency(myObj, 'my.cc')
mainObj=Object('main.cpp')
```

My question is:

1. How to specify this ShellExecution of protoc in SConstruct/SConscript?
2. How to make sure that the compilation of 'main.cpp' depends on the existence of 'my.cc', in another word, wait until 'my.cc' is generated and then execute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observations and assumptions are correct, *SCons* will not execute the single build commands in the order that you list them in the SConstruct files. It will run them based on the dependencies of the targets and source files in your build, either defined implicitly (header includes in C++, for example) or explicitly (via the `Depends()` method).

So you have to define and setup your dependencies correctly, such that *SCons* delivers the output that you want. For the special `protoc` case in your example, a special Builder exists that will help you to get the dependency graph right. It is available in our [ToolsIndex](https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/ToolsIndex), where also support for a variety of other languages and dialects can be found.

These special builders will emit the correct target nodes, e.g. when given a `*.proto` input file, and *SCons* is then able to automatically detect the dependency between the *protoc* input file and your `main` program if you say something like:

```
env=Environment(tools=['default','protoc'])
env.Protoc([], "test.proto")
env.Program('main', ['main.cpp'] + Glob('*.cc'))
```

The `Glob('*.cc')` will detect your `*.cc` files, coming out of the *protoc* Tool, and include them as dependencies for your final target `main`.

You can always write your own Builders and Emitters in *SCons*, which is the canonical way of making new tools/toolchains known to *SCons* dependency analysis. In the [UserGuide](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html), sect. "18 Writing Your Own Builders", and especially our [ToolsForFools Guide](https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/ToolsForFools) you can find more infos about this.

Comment: Thanks, but other then these external tool, how does Scons itself support my requirement? Thanks.

Comment: I've added references into the project's documentation. Adding a new *Builder*, and possibly an *Emitter*, is what is needed in your case. The provided links will explain how to do this in great detail.